# OG homepage URL

Tags: 6, organic-groups, path-aliases, uri

My current/default group front page is groupname/node/nid

But this is quite ugly, and when clicking on the site title the user is redirected to /group which does not display the group node but only the "river". Any way to fix this? I don't want to have to individually specify node/nid as the homepage in each individual group (in any case the Panels override that I have for the "group" node type displays "Home" as the title instead of the group name when I do this, for some reason)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your settings in the Pathauto module, and specify a pattern that you wish to use.